# Print a dictionary without brackets and parenthesis

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting

let's say you have a dictionary as follow:

```
{'A': (4, 1), 'C': (2, 0), 'B': (1, -1)}
```

How can you print it in the following format: each key and set of values in a new line without {} & ()

```
A 4 +1
C 2 0
B 1 -1
```

how to add "+" sign to the values, keep in mind values need to be integers.

This is what I have so far but can't figure out the "+" part:

```
for k, v in sorted_league.items():
print(k, *v ,sep=' ')'
```

Comment: You are magically adding a `+` sign in your print statement, if you want it there you probably need it as as string `+1`  in your dict

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you want but may be acceptable.  There is a `+` format string that reserves space for a sign:

```py
D = {'A': (4, 1), 'C': (2, 0), 'B': (1, -1)}

for k,(a,b) in D.items():
    print(f'{k} {a} {b:+}')
```

Output:

```
A 4 +1
C 2 +0
B 1 -1
```

Otherwise, this works but is more complicated:

```py
D = {'A': (4, 1), 'C': (2, 0), 'B': (1, -1)}

for k,(a,b) in D.items():
    print(f'{k} {a} {"+" if b>0 else ""}{b}')
```

Output:

```
A 4 +1
C 2 0
B 1 -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use f-strings, which will get you what you want (assuming you want the sign of all items to be displayed):

```
sorted_league = {'A': (4, 1), 'C': (2, 0), 'B': (1, -1)}
for k, v in sorted_league.items():
    print(k, f'{v[0]:+}', f'{v[1]:+}' ,sep=' ')
```

If you only want the sign of the second item in the tuple:

```
sorted_league = {'A': (4, 1), 'C': (2, 0), 'B': (1, -1)}
for k, v in sorted_league.items():
    print(k, v[0], f'{v[1]:+}' ,sep=' ')
```

Comment: sorted_league... I don't remember providing that..lol

Comment: The name itself is in the `for` loop in the question

Comment: But why would you not want to provide a variable name?